# How to expose a server with dynamic IPv6 address through OpenWrt firewall?

Tags: firewall, ipv6, openwrt

I want to make a web server running on my LAN available to the internet.  My router runs OpenWrt 22.03 with firewall4.

With IPv4, I would give the server a stable [RFC 1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918) address, then enable port forwarding on the router.

With IPv6, as I understand it, I should just give the server its own public IPv6 address, and then configure the router's firewall to allow inbound access to port 443 on that address.

But I don't understand how to specify the destination address when it can change based on the IPv6 prefix assigned by my ISP.  I could configure it for the specific address the server has now, but if my ISP assigns me a different prefix, that would make the server inaccessible until I edited the firewall config with the new address.

How can I specify a dynamic destination with OpenWrt firewall4?

Answer (score 0):

ipv6 address can change, but there's still a static part of it, ipv6 address' format is like A:B:C:D:E:F:G:H, this A:B:C:D comes from your idc or local ipv6 prefix, this E:F:G:H is static, so you can put this part of address in openwrt's firewall, and it's format is like ::E:F:G:H/0.
For example, you had a ipv6 address like 2001:0db8:3c4d:0015:0000:0000:1a2f:1a2b, the static part of it is 0000:0000:1a2f:1a2b, since the 0000 can be ignored, you can put ::1a2f:1a2b/0 in firewall as destination ip.

Comment: from your IDC -> from your ISP